# On-screen keyboard with app integration

Tags: touchscreen

I'm aware of `matchbox-keyboard`, but I'm looking for a more Android or iOS kind of keyboard solution. When selecting a text input, of type alpha or numeric, I would like the appropriate keyboard, text or numpad to appear. When unfocused, I'd like the keyboard to then disappear.

Does anyone know of a smartphone-like keyboard solution for the raspberry pi + touchscreen?

Update: I've found the `florence` keyboard. It has auto-hide which works under some conditions. The matchbox-keyboard can also auto-hide and pop up when used with an app that specifically signals matchbox-keyboard using it's library. You could also install an on-screen keyboard chrome extension if you're looking for a browser solution. I'll leave the answer open for an ideal mobile keyboard-like solution.